# Php change a number into another number that can be changed back to the original

Tags: php, encryption

Using PHP, I'm trying to encode a number into another number that I can decode back to the original number. The encoded string needs to be only numbers and should not contain anything else.

Eg: 10 becomes 573563547892 or something like that.

How can I do something like this in PHP? I tried quite a few encrypt decrypt functions, but none output only numbers.

I looking for something to use in a URL that isn't easy to guess.

So: http://www.me.com/index.PHP?page=20 becomes http://www.me.com/index.PHP?page=5705254782562466

Comment: why don't you just create a random number in the first place and search the page based on that? Do you need to use the actual id for this case?

Comment: If you've got a patch of binary that "won't output numbers" you need to do a rethink about base-10 numbering and simple string input/output.  (I could recommend xor with so many filled in bits, but basic encryption is much more robust, either way you'd be converting binary to base-10 or base-16 or base-64)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite heavy, but very good encryption, by using `ord` & `chr` a bit. While this works, consider other options: just being able to use *strings* rather then *numbers* already makes it a lot simpler (`base64_encode` etc.):

```
<?php
class Crypter {
  private $key = '';
  private $iv = '';
  function __construct($key,$iv){
    $this->key = $key;
    $this->iv  = $iv;
  }
  protected function getCipher(){
     $cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH,'','cbc','');
     mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, $this->key, $this->iv);
     return $cipher;
  }
  function encrypt($string){
     $binary = mcrypt_generic($this->getCipher(),$string);
     $string = '';
     for($i = 0; $i < strlen($binary); $i++){
        $string .=  str_pad(ord($binary[$i]),3,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
     }
     return $string;
  }
  function decrypt($encrypted){
     //check for missing leading 0's
     $encrypted = str_pad($encrypted, ceil(strlen($encrypted) / 3) * 3,'0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
     $binary = '';
     $values = str_split($encrypted,3);
     foreach($values as $chr){
        $chr = ltrim($chr,'0');
        $binary .= chr($chr);
     }
     return mdecrypt_generic($this->getCipher(),$binary);
  }
}

$crypt = new Crypter('secret key','12348765');
$encrypted = $crypt->encrypt(1234);
echo $encrypted.PHP_EOL;
//fake missing leading 0
$encrypted = ltrim($encrypted,'0');
echo $encrypted.PHP_EOL;
$decrypted = $crypt->decrypt($encrypted);
echo $decrypted.PHP_EOL;
```

Result:

```
057044206104214236155088
57044206104214236155088
1234
```

Comment: Did you just invent 3 character base-256 encoding?  Not too shabby.

Comment: Heh, I still voted for Sorin's answer though, I don't assume this kind of heavy encryption is actually _needed_ ;) (And I shudder to think why _numbers_ is a requirement, as if it has anything to do with integers, the max integer value is quite quickly reached.)

Comment: Is it necessary to do `$encrypted = ltrim($encrypted,'0');`?

Comment: @Norman: no, it's not. That was just to show that a likely break in transit (dropping starting`0`'s on a number) can be recovered from. But you could see that yourself: just removing that line make the rest still work.

Comment: BTW: note I mentioned this was a _heavy_ encryption algorithm. For the sake of speed, you could _cache_ the encrypt / decrypt results in a server-side cache like memcached or apc to limit the amount of time spent / make it quicker if the cache is filled.

Comment: This thing is safe to use in a production environment, right? Any reason why I shouldn't, other than the heaviness.

Comment: Also, the decrypt return a `string` type, even if it's all numbers. Any way to overcome that?

Comment: @Norman:no. With this encrypt, you can easily step over the 64-bit mark, which means casting to int silently casts to float, which results in loss of precision and makes it undecryptable. Could you perhaps elaborate _why_ you need it to be an `integer`?

Comment: (`var_dump((int)"57044206104214236155088");` == `int(9223372036854775807)`)

Comment: I'd like to do `if(is_numeric($decrypted))` { pass the value to the sql}

Comment: `var_dump(is_numeric("57044206104214236155088"));` => `true`. (_"Returns `TRUE` if var is a number **or a numeric string**, `FALSE` otherwise."_)

Answer (score 3):

Why not using a mathematicat operation on the original number? like `x` becomes `x * y + z`. you would only have to make the reverse operation to get the original number. consider using large enough prime numbers for `y` and/or `z`